# Wordpress menu and child items

Tags: wordpress

how can i get the children items of an active menu in WP?!

I display menu with wp_nav_menu(), but i wonna display the child items in another block.

Thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sure that isn't possible without any custom code.

How about this plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-navigation-list-plugin-navt/

Answer (score 2):

There are some long code examples here: [WordPress › Support » wp_nav_menu: List only 2nd level (separate submenu)?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/413314?replies=13)